# Check if a number is a palindrome - fails for 11,22 etc

Tags: python, integer, palindrome

The following code is for a coding exercise on Leetcode - I am checking if a number is a palindrome or not (without converting it into a string). I am unable to understand why this code fails for numbers like 11, 22, 33 etc.

```
def isPalindrome(self, x):
    #x is an integer
    digit = 0
    reverse = 0

    #Single digit numbers will be palindromes
    if x >= 0 and x < 10:
        return True

    #fetch individual digits and build the reverse number    
    while x > 0:
        digit = x % 10
        reverse = (reverse * 10) + digit
        x = x / 10

    if x == reverse:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: You are modifying `x` repeatedly in your loop and then trying to use it in your comparison afterwards. This will never return `True` for multi-digit numbers.

Comment: @Phylogenesis That is also true but not enough. OP, run the code in your mind for 22.. Don't you notice anything wrong with it? like the `reverse = (reverse * 10) + digit` or the `x = x / 10` ?

Comment: how silly of me! Thank you for clearing that up

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I'm not sure what else is wrong. The algorithm itself looks okay to me.

Comment: In my maschine it does not ran unless on top of your suggestion the `x = x / 10` is changed to `x = x // 10`. This might very well be a python version though. The `reverse` definition is indeed ok.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Oh I see. Yes, the `/` operator was changed between Python 2 and Python 3. In Python 2, it does integer division in the operands are both `int` or `long`.

Comment: @user1528508 Why not just convert it into a string and test, would be so much easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to convert it to a string and check it that way. I've used `[::-1]` to reverse the string and then compared it with the original.

```
def isPalindrome(x):
    if str(x) == str(x)[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for x in range(100):
    print(x, isPalindrome(x))
```

If you also want to test that its actually a number, use `x.isdigit()`, this will return `True` for integers.